# Is it valid to set img src="about:blank"?

Tags: html, image, tags

Background: I need to have an *inline* element to which I can apply width and height via CSS.
AFAIK, img is the only way to have this behavior, currently.

I would rather not have the image point to a transparent pixel GIF on the server. It may be cached, but browsers queue it nevertheless, slowing down overall page speed. Other clients might not be caching at all.

**PS** No, floating div is not sufficient, it behaves differently from inline elements.

**EDIT** Sorry, I should have inserted the term "cross browser" somewhere. It must at least be working for FF≥2, IE≥7 and current Safari.

Comment: EDIT: Sorry, I should have inserted the term "cross browser" somewhere. It must at least be working for FF>=2, IE>=7 and current Safari.

Comment: This begs the question: why? What purpose does the element serve?

Comment: @PeterP: Click the "edit" link to alter the question.

Comment: @outis: Sorry, wrong link - happens to me every time

Comment: @outis: The element must be sizeable, but at the same time it should be possible to place it within another inline-element, or have it aligned properly like any inline element.

Comment: @PeterP: that's a requirement for the element, not the purpose. What's the overall goal for the element to fulfill? Is it a placeholder? Is it a spacer?

Comment: @outis: no, it is an interactive element

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the ["data:" URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to embed an image.

Other replaced elements might also work. Setting display to "inline-block" might also be worth looking into.

Comment: looks good, however it seems not to be crossbrowser enough for my purposes (IE7) - sorry for not specifying this right away

Comment: However, I reviewed inline-block (thought it would not be working in IE7) which seems to work quite alright. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @PeterP: what are your purposes, exactly?

Comment: @outis: purpose is to have interactive elements which can be reused in an inline context too (like an image). after all, it is about accomplishing a certain layout without (mis-)using spacer images and likewise.
I used inline-block now, had some fun with IE7/6 (did no longer work fine when it got more complex), works fine now.
Thanks for your inspiration :)

Comment: Note that src="data:" triggers security warning dialog on an https page in IE7, were src="about:blank" does not.

Comment: FYI, [a 1x1 blank GIF is `data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7`](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1199635)

Answer (score 1):

Can you set:

```
display:inline-block;
width:50px;
height:10px;
```

IIRC, images are an "inline block" element, thus they can be rendered inline in text strings, but still have block-like properties.

Comment: inline-block may have strange behavior in IE6/7: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Comment: Thanks for you input... Always thought inline-block would not be working in IE7, as I reviewed it, I noticed it does (at least it does in a simple example)

Answer (score 1):

I guess it will be *valid* in the W3C validator sense, because the validator does not check whether the link is a resource or not.

However, valid in the broader sense, I would say it is not. An `src` attribute is required in the IMG tag, and I would say must point to a valid image resource.

I find outis`s "data: URI" idea the best way.

If that doesn't work, a transparent image is your best bet. It's one call, it's a few bytes at best, and will be cached by most clients.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'll try inline-block first :)

Answer (score 1):

Using "about:blank" as src will cause IE to display red X-boxes. This line of CSS prevents this (in IE 8+), but it's still all a bit hacky:

```
img[src="about:blank"] {visibility:hidden}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish the same thing with a

tag.

```
<p style="height: 400px; width: 400px; background-color: #ffcccc;">&nbsp;</p>
```

Height and width are settable. This should be across the common browsers, however I have not been able to test Safari or Chrome using it.

Comment: But that's not inline. You either need to add absolute positioning or have the element float. Both solutions would not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<span>` tag with a `&nbsp;` in it - totally valid - then set it's width and height in CSS, also apply `display: block;`

Using an empty `<span>` tag means it will be ignored by screen readers and it won't show up as a broken image when styles are disabled.

It'll also not use up any more bandwidth.

:-D

Comment: Thanks for your proposal, however, block is not inline, which is an important difference in my case.